# Framework for Android+iOS app with tutorial, embedded website, push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notifications

I have a PHP website which I want my users to be able to download an "app" version from the Play Store (Android) and App Store (iOS).

My idea was to build a hybrid app with Cordova/Ionic or similar framework.
I would like to make a native "intro/tutorial" view and then redirect to a "webview/iframe/embed version of my website" when the introduction is finished.
Also, I will need the phone to receive push notifications.

Which technology/framework is more optimal to achieve this kind of development. I would like to avoid Angular/React. Is it viable to achieve it with a plain cordova app?